# cannot login to the ftp server

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Anyone has an idea what will be the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash -x

HOST='192.163.3.3'
USER='ftpuser'
PASSWD='apple'
Logfile=a.log

while :; do
ftp -n -p -v $HOST < example.script >> a.log
grep -qF "Connected" a.log &&
grep -qF "File successfully transferred" a.log && break
done

quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
```

example.script contains

```
 put example.txt
```

after running it gives

```
 grep: a.log: No such file or directory
 grep: a.log: No such file or directory
                .
                .
```

example.script and the created a.log is on /home directory

the a.log contains

```
 Connected to 192.163.3.3.
 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
 220-You are user number 9 of 50 allowed.
 220-Local time is now 14:38. Server port: 21.
 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
 Remote system type is UNIX.
 Using binary mode to transfer files.
 local: example.txt remote: example.txt
 530 You aren't logged in
 Passive mode refused.
 221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
 221 Logout.
```

why cant i logged in?

```
  HOST='192.163.3.3'
  USER='ftpuser'
  PASSWD='apple'
  FILE='example.txt'
  Logfile=a.log

  ftp -n -p -v $HOST << SCRIPT_END >> a.log
  quote USER $USER
  quote PASS $PASSWD

  put $FILE
  SCRIPT_END
```

with this it works but why? what will be the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually find creating a [netrc](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.commadmn/doc/commadmndita/tcpip_netrc.htm) file and using that to at least start my FTP session gets me around a lot of issues with scripting an ftp session. Most ftp programs give you the option of using an alternate *netrc* file, so you don't need to setup one at `$HOME/.netrc`.

I believe you just need a one liner like this:

```
machine 192.163.3.3 login ftpuser password apple
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it because I don't have ftp setup anywhere. Everything here is `scp`/`ssh`/`sftp`. Here's an [example](http://docs.cray.com/books/2148_3.3/html-2148_3.3/c15akljgm.html) `.netrc` file.

Answer (score 3):

Your FTP daemon is refusing passive mode file transfers (PASV command). You have to enable passive mode transfers on Pure-FTPd. This site has nice tutorial on how to do it:
[Getting passive FTP connections to work through a firewall properly](http://www.theserverpages.com/articles/servers/cpanel/tweaks/Getting_passive_FTP_connections_to_work_through_a_firewall_properly.html) - scroll down to section Setting up the FTP Server (Pure-FTPD).

Comment: another script works, but runs only once, with this script will be the problem

Comment: Can you write a one line description of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining about being in passive mode, I would remove the -p from the command or allow passive FTP.

-p 
Use passive mode for data transfers. Allows use of ftp in environments where a firewall prevents connections from the outside world back to the client machine. Requires that the ftp server support the PASV command. This is the default now for all clients (ftp and pftp) due to security concerns using the PORT transfer mode. The flag is kept for compatibility only and has no effect anymore.

Comment: if i remove grep: a.log: No such file or directory
ftp: bind: Address already in use